# ¿Como puedo conectarme a una base de datos MySql, mediante webhook en Dialogflow?

Tags: mysql, firebase, google-api

Lo que pasa es que, estoy trabajando con *Dialogflow*, dado a que estoy creando un Chatbot para una empresa, entonces mediante webhook, en las opciones de Fulfillment me estoy conectando a una base de datos Firebase asi.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

    // initialise DB connection
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
      databaseURL: 'https://<Nombre de la base de datos>.firebaseio.com',
    });

    process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';

    exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
      console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
      console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

      function handleAge(agent) {
        const edad = agent.parameters.edad;
         //agent.add(`Muchas gracias...`);


        //return admin.database().ref('ageInfo').once("value").then((snapshot) => {
        //  var averageAge = snapshot.child("runningAverage").val();
        //  agent.add(`Our recorded average age is ` + averageAge);
        //});

         return admin.database().ref('ageInfo').transaction((ageInfo) => {
          if(ageInfo !== null) {
            let oldAverage = ageInfo.runningAverage;
            let oldTotalCount = ageInfo.totalCount;
            let newAverage = (oldAverage * oldTotalCount + edad) / (oldTotalCount + 1);
            ageInfo.runningAverage = newAverage;
            ageInfo.totalCount+=1;
            //agent.add(`Nuestra edad promedio registrada es ` + newAverage);
          }
          return ageInfo;
        }, function(error, isSuccess) {
          console.log('Actualizar el éxito de transacción de edad promedio: ' + isSuccess);
        });


      }

      // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
      let intentMap = new Map();
      intentMap.set('preguntaedad', handleAge);
      agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });
```

mi pregunta es si alguna posibilidad de que me pueda conectar a una base de datos, para ingresar datos ingresados por el usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Mira, es posible, veo 2 posibilidades, que hagas el webhook en el mismo servidor que tengas la base de datos y no en firebase(es un poco más tedioso creo yo), o puedes crear una API o servidor que acepte peticiones POST(escritura) en el cual tengas la BD y de tu webhook mandes los datos a  el servidor, en este caso firebase te pedirá que cambies a un plan de pago por que esté solo permite hacer peticiones a api's de Google en el plan gratuito.